# How do you display greek characters on a PyQt4 GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-2.6, qspinbox

I am a bit of a noob, so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I am writing a program to perform scientific simulations, some of the parameters for which are measured in micrometres. The suffix for such parameters is µm where the greek symbol mu preceeds the m for metre.

Ideally i would like to set the suffix for my spin boxes to be µm, but i get the following error: "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character"

I am comfortable setting the suffix for spin boxes but have no idea about character encoding. I am using Python 2.6 and PyQt4 on windows 7, and this is an example of how i have tried to do this:

```
spin1 = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
spin1.setSuffix("µm")
```

This has been really irritating me and i can't get my head around any of the solutions i have found online, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use unicode literals `u'µm'`? Check out http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/. Off: A exclamation mark does not belong into a question. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Using unicode object instead of simple string:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

# Your code ...

spin1 = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
spin1.setSuffix(u"µm")
```

Comment: oh man, that didn't work for me, i guess i need to specify what the u does at some point? so up top somewhere something like: # u = utf-8 would that work?

Comment: Add ``# -*- coding: utf8 -*-`` at the top of file. See: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/